# Claiming Tokens failed first try because i set GWEI too low, second try pending without Gas?

Tags: metamask

first of all thank you for your help in advance!

i tried to claim some free tokens but only had ~7$ in my MM left, so i though i'll give it a try setting the Gas money to the bare minimum that MM allows willing to wait for a day or two.

This is the first Transaction (failed):
https://etherscan.io/tx/0xeae0432a71ab6af9cb98cf9f22595c1cb41bac1fa6e0e7d852316a74f77c12d5

This is the second Transaction (pending):
https://etherscan.io/tx/0xd3397eadc9cf36cf11be7b7d2e35d3e3a6930aa8b64f1ea9853021d8df5e53e4

I'm not sure whats going on here and we the secong transaction is associated with zero costs.

Can someone by chance shed some light in the dark for me? That would be highly appreciated!

Is the money gone? what is the second pending transaction doing? The Gas is already gone from my MM.

Thanks again & a merry christmas to all of you!
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

your first failed `out of gas` transaction costed you 0.0017485 ether ($6.89).

and your second was dropped (the nodes saw you couldn't pay the transaction fee - you have only $0.23)